# How do we perceive weight?

Tags: perception

How do we perceive weight of our own body or something we are holding?

It might turn out that we don't perceive weight so is it subjective? Is it similar to pain, or something different?

Comment: Do you mean the weight of our body? Or the weight if something we hold or carry?

Comment: @Marzipanherz hi! Both...

Comment: @santimirandarp We sense tension in our muscles and tendons which are affected by the force that is opposing the movement (hence by the weight of the object we are trying to move; here "object" can also refer to one's own body). Would this answer your question?

Comment: There are specific nerve cells that sense this tension in the tendon and send the signal up to the brain. Without considering a formal definition of "sense" (I don't think there is a commonly agreed upon definition) but just to my intuitive notion of a "sense", I would most definitely consider this a sense, yes.

Comment: @santimirandarp People are voting to close your question as unclear; I thought it was fairly clear to me, but if people want to close a question that I don't think needs to be closed, I feel like the best way to prevent that is to do whatever possible to remove the reason for closure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This would most likely come under the category of Proprioception - the sense of how our bodies are arranged in the world, and how much effort each part of our body is expending.

From Wikipedia, 'In humans, it is provided by proprioceptors in skeletal striated muscles (muscle spindles) and tendons (Golgi tendon organ) and the fibrous membrane in joint capsules. '.

So our brain receives signals from muscles, tendons and joints, and integrates these into an internal sense of how we are arranged and what our bodies are busy doing.